# How to cast string to ascii value in java?

Tags: java, ascii

I have new assignment and since I am new to JAVA I don't know how to make it work, I have searched this website frequently but all the solutions which were suggested didn't work out for me or I didn't use them properly, I would be grateful if someone helps me... 
the code below is the most simple solution I could find but still doesn't work...

I want to get inputs like names from people and change them to numbers (int)...it says it is not possible to cast from string to int ... !!

```
 package loveindex;
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.math.BigInteger;

public class LoveIndex {

private static Scanner scan;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    String testi = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(testi);
    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    String testi2 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(testi2);

    int ascii = (int) testi;
    int ascii = (int) testi2;
  }

}
```

Comment: sorry I edited my question :(

Comment: What ascii character would you expect "Fnord" to convert to?

Comment: How do you want your strings converted to numbers? Give us some examples of how you expect this to work

Comment: Each character in a Java String is a 16-bit unsigned UTF-16 value.  For "normal" characters (anything on a standard English keyboard) the character values are all less than 127 and map to the ASCII character set (Google it).  You can use String's `charAt(N)` to retrieve the Nth character of the String as a `char` value, and that can be assigned to an `int` with no loss of information.

Comment: for example I get name like "John" and I am supposed to get the AScII value which has to be numbers i mean "integer" (the famous table thing) and later on I will use them in some equation to make love index....

Comment: There are 4 numbers in "John".  Use `String nameJohn = "John"; int firstChar = nameJohn.charAt(0); ... int fourthChar = nameJohn.charAt(3);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can Try This:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    String testi = scan.nextLine();
    char[] ascii1 = testi.toCharArray();

    for(char ch:ascii1){
        System.out.println((int)ch+"  ");
    }


    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    String testi2 = scan.nextLine();
    char[] ascii2 = testi2.toCharArray();

    for(char ch:ascii2){
        System.out.println((int)ch+"  ");
    }

  scan.close();
}
```

Comment: :: this works fine but could you tell me how to sum up the chars at the end? for example for a name "John" I get 4 int and I need to sum them or multiply them in different equations... but i dont know how to use them now :(

Comment: I found it ... tnx any way :P

Answer (score 2):

Achieve the same in a concise way by employing Java 8's lambda function.
From your comment (at the accepted answer) you need the sum of the characters at the end?

```
String str = "name";
int sum = str.chars().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to assign a `String` to an `int` which the 2 of which are incompatible. You can get the ascii value of a single character

```
int ascii = testi.charAt(0);
```

Comment: @HamedFazilat it will give the ascii of the first character in `testi`

Comment: @johny sorry but wuuuut ? u mean it is going to convert only the first letter like J from Johny ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert string to ascii like that. You can convert a character to ascii

```
int ascii = (int)some_char;
```