# How do i encrypt a message to ascii characters without using big integer? java rsa

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

```
public static String encrypt(int p, int q, int k, String m) {}
```

Hi I want to implement an encryption which does not use big integers, it should convert each character in a string to ASCII characters? Any ideas on how i would do this? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-string-to-ascii-numeric-value-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724576/how-to-cast-string-to-ascii-value-in-java

Comment: Even if you encrypt each character in the plaintext string separately, you will need BigInteger, because even small numbers for RSA quickly break out of the limited size for integers or longs in Java.

Comment: Thanks you so much, and ye i guess big integer is needed eventually however im just doing some very low level work and wont really use very large numbers as such.